# Is there a way to have a void always running in java

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm trying to make a stat system for my game however i cant figure out how to make the stats go down over a certain period of time I've got the code to do so but i just need it to be always running so that my J frame can update and display the changed stat.

```
package pandacare;
import java.util.Random;
public class PandaCare {

Random r = new Random();

int HWT;

int hunger = 0;
int fun = 0;
int thirst = 0;
int energy = 0;
int hygiene = 0;
int points = 0;
int coins = 1000;
int total = hunger + fun +thirst + energy + hygiene;

public void hungerWait(){
    int Low = 5;
    int High = 30;
    HWT = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
}

public void hungerDown(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(HWT);
    }           
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    hunger --;
}



}
```

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea what you're asking.

Comment: sorry i think i explained it very badly. ill post the code

Comment: If that's your code, it's sleeping in the main thread, meaning the entire app stops.  (Except, of course, the method never gets called.)

Comment: `to have a void always running` what?

Comment: You, at a minimum, need to learn about threads.  You're a little bit over your head at present.

Comment: i want it to keep checking a void so that a number on the jframe will update after a certain amount of time

Comment: you might want to take a look at `SwingWorker`.

Comment: i know im a bit of a noob to this sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a while(true) loop? I don't really understand the question. A while(true) loop will continue to execute everything in the brackets over and over again. Example:

```
int i = 0;
while(true){i++; 
            System.out.println(i);
           }
```

Comment: why cant i access a variable from inside my while loop? @Krzysztof

Comment: @Dane Ashman You have to declare the variable outside the loop first, then use the variable inside the loop.